# How can I excute automator's shell script in same setting with my local terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, zsh, automator

I'd like to use automator's shell in same environment setting as local terminal does.

I have iMac and Macbook pro. On both, I installed `jq` command in `/opt/homebrew/bin`
On iMac I can use `jq` without telling absolute path in automator's shell script. Because automator's shell script can refer `/opt/homebrew/bin` It returns `/opt/homebrew/bin` by `echo $PATH`

But, on Macbook, I have to use absolute path in automator's shell script.
This is because in automator's shell script doesn't refer `/opt/homebrew/bin` where local terminal refers.

As iMac automator's shell script is set up to refer `/opt/homebrew/bin`, there must be the way I can set paths for automator's shell script.
But I don't remember how I set up like that.

So the question is how I can set automator's shell script to refer the directory wherever I want to?

I googled it and people say the setting of your terminal and automator's shell script isdifferent.
But google can't teach me how to set up automator's shell script same as local terminal.

Any idea for this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Try setting `PATH` in `.zshenv` instead of `.zshrc`.  A bit more about `zsh` startup files is [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Intro/intro_3.html).

Comment: @Gairfowl
Thank you for your comment! I added path on `.zshenv` and it worked! I refer to the link you gave me for additional information about zsh. Thank you!